# Why do authors say conflicting things regarding leak-free stages in their paper?

Tags: multiparty-computation

In [this paper](http://web.mit.edu/eboyle/www/LR-MPC-STOC12.pdf) the last sentence of the first paragraph in the abstract states:

> We assume a (necessary) “leak-free” preprocessing stage.

But then later on in section 1.4 they say

> Another interesting open question is to construct a leakage- resilient
>   MPC protocol without assuming any leak-free stages,

Why do they say the leak-free stage is necessary but then later on they say it's an interesting open question ? When they say it's necessary doesn't that imply there is no open question (i.e. not debatable) ?

Is there any research done on leak-free stageS?

Comment: The "'leak-free' preprocessing stage" is a necessary part of their MPC protocol. $\hspace{1.78 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer - Yes - if it is necessary then why does it become and open question late on in the paper? I'm still unclear about this.

Comment: I think they are saying assuming leak free is necessary to prove security for their protocol, but it woul be really cool (thus an open problem) to design a protocol that can tolerate leaks in any stage.

Comment: @mikeazo - that makes sense to me.  I guess there's no other explanation that makes sense so I'll mark it as correct if you answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they are saying assuming leak free is necessary to prove security for their protocol, but it would be really cool (thus an open problem) to design a protocol that can tolerate leaks in any stage.